# Excel Combining of VLOOKUP with another SUBSTITUTE, REPLACE, or IF THEN

Tags: excel, replace, formula, vlookup, substitution

[image]

I am looking to be able to type in an ITEM CODE from column J into column F and have that replaced with its corresponding FULL DESCRIPTION in column K. From there it will lookup its corresponding cost and populate into column H.

I have gotten as far as to get the cost matched up with 
=VLOOKUP(F3,$K$3:$L$50,2,FALSE)
but I can't seem to get column F to SUBSTITUTE or REPLACE. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a date in columns J:L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea about `SUBSTITUTE` and `REPLACE`.

You cannot enter something into a cell and have a formula to have the cell "`replaced with its corresponding FULL DESCRIPTION`".

Functions can not change the values of other cells.  Functions  *return* a value to the cell in which they are placed.

What you are asking about could be accomplished with VBA:

- On worksheet change, check if the cell is changed.
- If the cell has changed:

  - turn off event updates
  - do your lookup
  - update the cell
  - turn on event updates

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [S**UBSTITUTE function (Excel)**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)
- Office.com : [**REPLACE function (Excel)**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/replace-replaceb-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a)

Comment: Ah I realized that just after you answered. My solution was to use another column to assign it a value that corresponds to what I want to have filled. Thus utilizing two separate VLOOKUP

Comment: Thank you very much for responding :-)